# What does starring a repository on GitHub do?

Tags: notifications, github

GitHub rolled out their new [notifications and stars](https://github.com/blog/1204-notifications-stars) feature.

But does starring do anything for a repository?

Is it just to show support or interest? Is there any functional purpose to the user?

If not, why should I use them? Do other users, or maybe even GitHub, benefit from me starring a repository?

Answer (score 110, accepted):

[image]

The big difference between **watching** and **starring** a project comes down to **notifications**.

If you're **watching** a repository, you'll receive notifications for all discussions: project issues, pull requests, comments on commits and any other comments. If you’re not watching a repo, you’ll just receive notifications for the discussions in which you participate.

On the other hand, if you **star** repositories, you're showing your appreciation as well as keeping track of repositories that you find interesting without overwhelming your feed with activity notifications.

As stated in this [GitHub blog post](https://github.blog/2012-08-06-notifications-stars/#:%7E:text=A%20quick%20note%3A%20activity%20from%20starred%20repositories%20will%20not%20show%20up%20in%20your%20dashboard%20feed),

> A quick note: activity from starred repositories will not show up in your dashboard feed.

Another thing worth noting is that any repositories you were previously **watching** can now be found on your **stars** page. If you want to go back to **watching** them, you’ll need to change them over yourself. There’s also a new auto-watch feature: If you’re given **push** access to a repository, GitHub automatically adds it to your **watch list**.

You can see a list of your starred repos at [github.com/stars](http://github.com/stars).

[image]

And trending (popular) starred repos at [github.com/trending](https://github.com/trending)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

An additional advantage to starring is that 3rd party services can use them to provide custom notifications. For instance, [Sibbell](https://sibbell.com/about/), [Gitnotifier.io](https://gitnotifier.io/), etc. offer services for these types of notifications.